# Why Postgres jsonb_agg function is giving error operation & does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, operator-keyword, jsonb

I'm running to this problem and haven't found any information related to it. On the same Postgres server (version 13.2), the below query works in one database, but is giving "ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb & jsonb" in another database.

`select jsonb_agg('{"a": "b", "c": "d"}'::jsonb - 'a');`

This is the full error output:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb & jsonb
LINE 1: SELECT json_cur_in & json_next_in
                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT json_cur_in & json_next_in
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function jsonb_agg_statef(jsonb,jsonb) line 3 at assignment
SQL state: 42883
```

The select query above is a simplified example, not the actual code. But it shows the same error. The jsonb_agg is the built-in function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the reason for the jsonb_agg in your example? You are not aggregating anything. But the query [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fdafd7730d8072b8bb7675253b8c73ba) there must be something you are not telling us.

Comment: Someone been fooling around in the system catalogs? Or did someone create their own version of `jsonb_agg` and overload the function? In `psql` `\df *.jsonb_agg` will show you the latter. The system supplied should have a line like: `pg_catalog | jsonb_agg | jsonb            | anyelement          | agg`

Comment: The error is correct there is no `&`  operator for `jsonb`, so I'm guessing someone has been getting inventive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the example I've given is not the actual production code, but it gives the same error. I've simplified it down for brevity.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I updated the description with full error output. The & is probably used internally in Postgres. I have double checked and we don't have a user-defined jsonb_agg function.

Comment: The error is coming from the user function `jsonb_agg_statef` in the query `SELECT json_cur_in & json_next_in`. That is not going to work as again there is no `&` operator for `jsonb`.

Comment: You claim that "*The jsonb_agg is the built-in function.*", but what about `-`? Has it been redefined?

Comment: Thanks to @AdrianKlaver, I've found the problem. Someone created their own version of jsonb_agg and jsonb_agg_statef and put that in the public schema. Problem solved!

Comment: There is no built in function `jsonb_agg_statef`.  Did not `\df *.jsonb_agg`  find the rogue function?

Comment: Adrian, that is correct. There is no built-in jsonb_agg_statef function. \df *.jsonb_agg showed 2 versions of jsonb_agg: one in pg_catalog and the other in public. The one in public schema was an user-defined to override the built-in, which calls jsonb_agg_statef. Thank you Adrian, you saved my day. Now how do I mark your comment as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `select jsonb_agg('{"a": "b", "c": "d"}'::jsonb - 'a');` and getting this error `ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb & jsonb"` pointed at there being another version of `jsonb_agg()` being play as there is no `&` operator for `jsonb`. This indicates a user created function, by a user who did not actually test it, is overloading `jsonb_agg()`. In `psql` doing `\df *.jsonb_agg` would show what and where the other function is.